# how to create several columns from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, facebook-graph-api

So I am trying to parse Facebook ads data using the Facebook Graph API, I was able to create and get all the data I needed, however two of the returned items are lists of dictionaries, specifically the ***actions*** field and ***action_value*** field, each of which contains the name of the action and the value of that action.

I have added the 2 list of dicts as is in my dataframe, however, I need to actually have each name/value in a column, the column name would be the action name from the dict, and the value would be the action value from the same dict. so instead of having for example 30 columns per row, I would like to have 28 + however many dicts are within the actions or action_value lists. [image: df returned with the action value and actions dicts]

[image: image from the table in the datase]
Please notice how the action_values and action columns consist of several values 'which are dicts' I would like to have each of the items within the dict to be a column of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your point. You need to extract every k v pairs from the list of dictionaries to generate a flat one. Here's some code:

```
import pandas as pd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [{"action_values": [{"action_type": "post", "value": 1},{"action_type": "purchase", "value": 1}],
             "actions": [{"action_type": "post_1", "value": 1}, {"action_type": "purchase", "value": 2}],
             "click": 123}]
    cleaned = []
    for i in data:
        for action_values in i["action_values"]:
            tmp = {**i}
            tmp.pop("action_values")
            tmp.pop("actions")
            for k, v in action_values.items():
                tmp[f"action_values/{k}"] = v
            for action in i["actions"]:
                for k2, v2 in action.items():
                    tmp[f"actions/{k2}"] = v2
                cleaned.append(tmp.copy())
    df = pd.DataFrame(cleaned)
    print(df)
```

Thus, In the before, you have one row in df, with action_values field assigns with list of two dictionaries, actions field assign with list of two dictionaries. After processing, you get `2 * 2 = 4` rows in df.

Comment: I think this has got me closer to what I want to do, however I can't see except only 1 of the 2 items in the dict, which is purchase..

Comment: @KareemRashwan I have updated the answer. Firstly, you need to delcare tmp inside for loop. Secondly, you need to append copy of tmp into cleaned. Actually, you can use `itertools` to generate rathet manually.

Comment: thanks a lot, it still didn't really work on my case, but I was able to use and reference some of it to get mine to work, this part was especially helpful         

***tmp[f"action_values/{k}"] = v***

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try pd.DataFrame.fromdict()

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [{'action_type': 'dataframe', 'value': 1},
        {'action_type': 'read','value': 1}, 
        {'action_type': 'post','value': 25}]

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

```
    action_type     value
0   dataframe        1
1   read             1
2   post            25
```

Comment: this will append the values beneath each other, cause a huge number of row duplication for each value in action_values or actions

Comment: Then I have not really understood what you what to achieve

Comment: I have a dataframe that has 2 dictionary datatype columns. each of the dict columns has several values inside of it like what you have suggested above, I need to expand those into columns of their own..